# HQL joins repeats records on Hibernate 5.2/Spring 4.3 (no eager fetched, mapped to Set, only inner joins)

Tags: spring, hibernate, join, annotations, hql

Hello.
It may seem that this question is made before  but I cannot see any answer in internet to this concrete case.
This is my starting point: 
HQL joins repeats records  on Hibernate 5.2/Spring 4.3. This is a simple Many to One/One to many mapping:  I have my Root Entity (Usuarios) and my Child entity (Perfiles). 
I tried the simple example with Oracle 11, and MySQL 5, and it always repeats the root Entity results. I dont if it has to be taht way... I doubt it (I am not new to Hibernate)

The configuration is OK  I already revidsed it a bunch of times.
The problem with this simple HQL, is that it repeats the object Usuarios for each one of its children (Perfiles), so if I have one Usuario with 3 Perfiles, it appears 3 times.

No left joins, no EAGER fetching, Usuarios is mapping to a Set of Perfiles. Everything is alrigth!!!!! I cant believe it is repeating the records. Of course if i put a distinct there, I get one simple object Usuarios  (thats what i want of course), perfectly populated with its sets and subObjetc.. like Perfiles. But i Cannot find why it is acting that way,  something must be wrong if I have to write the distinc in the HQL.
Here are my two objects:

```
<pre><code>
select u from Usuarios u
inner join u.perfiles p
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuarios")
public class Usuarios implements java.io.Serializable {

private int usuarioId;
private TcTiposDocumentos tcTiposDocumentos;
private Usuarios usuarioAlta;
private Usuarios usuarioUltModif;
private Usuarios usuarioBaja;

private String nombreApellidos;
private String email;
private String numTelefono;
private Set<Perfiles> perfiles = new HashSet<Perfiles>(0);

public Usuarios() {
}


@Id
@Column(name = "USUARIO_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public int getUsuarioId() {
    return this.usuarioId;
}

public void setUsuarioId(int usuarioId) {
    this.usuarioId = usuarioId;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "COD_TIPO_DOCUMENTO", nullable = false)
public TcTiposDocumentos getTcTiposDocumentos() {
    return this.tcTiposDocumentos;
}

public void setTcTiposDocumentos(TcTiposDocumentos tcTiposDocumentos) {
    this.tcTiposDocumentos = tcTiposDocumentos;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "COD_USUARIO_BAJA")
public Usuarios getUsuarioBaja() {
    return this.usuarioBaja;
}

public void setUsuarioBaja(Usuarios ub) {
    this.usuarioBaja = ub;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "usuarios")
public Set<Perfiles> getPerfiles() {
    return this.perfiles;
}
public void setPerfiles(Set<Perfiles> perfileses) {
    this.perfiles = perfileses;
}
}

//CHILD ENTITY
Entity
@Table(name = "perfiles")
public class Perfiles implements java.io.Serializable {

private int perfilId;
private ComunidadesRegante comunidadesRegante;
private TcRoles tcRoles;
private Usuarios usuarios;

public Perfiles() {
}

public Perfiles(int perfilId, TcRoles tcRoles, Usuarios usuarios) {
    this.perfilId = perfilId;
    this.tcRoles = tcRoles;
    this.usuarios = usuarios;
}

public Perfiles(int perfilId, ComunidadesRegante comunidadesRegante, TcRoles 
tcRoles, Usuarios usuarios) {
    this.perfilId = perfilId;
    this.comunidadesRegante = comunidadesRegante;
    this.tcRoles = tcRoles;
    this.usuarios = usuarios;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "PERFIL_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
public int getPerfilId() {
    return this.perfilId;
}

public void setPerfilId(int perfilId) {
    this.perfilId = perfilId;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "COD_USUARIO", nullable = false)
public Usuarios getUsuarios() {
    return this.usuarios;
}

public void setUsuarios(Usuarios usuarios) {
    this.usuarios = usuarios;
}

}


</code></pre>
```

Comment: why are you doing the join, if you are only interested in usarios? what about a simple <pre><code>select * from usarios</code></pre>?

Comment: I need The object Perfiles (profiles) inside Usuarios. It is HQL not SQL. The query is  is:select u from Usuarios u
inner join u.perfiles p

Comment: Your perfiles attribute is a OneToMany in Usuarios, not OneToOne. For one row of Usuarios your have more rows of Perfiles. So, you can remove the join because, perfiles attribute is encapsuled in your Usuarios entity

Comment: If I remove the join (in fact is it a join fetch), The perfiles object inside Usuarios dosent get populated. I am trying to get a usuarios Object filled with its perfiles all populated via HQL, The select is :
    select u from Usuarios u inner join fetch u.perfiles
All dependencies are Lazy by default, if a join fetch is not made, the perfiles object will not be filled. The problema is thta Usuarios repeats records as many times as perfiles it has. Whats wrong with HQL??? I made thousands of these in another Project....

Answer (score 0):

I guess thats the way Hibernate 5 works. If you are using HQL, you'll have to use the  "distinct" keyword in all the querys in order to get not repeated results (it works OK, no major problems happened).